# Realm open/close practice

Tags: android, realm

How bad is it to open a [`Realm`](https://github.com/realm/realm-java) instance in the app `onCreate` and leave it open for the whole `Application` lifecycle, only closing it when the application is killed? (assuming I won't call it from another thread)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is perfectly safe to do, but if you don't close the Realm when your app goes in the background there is a higher chance your app will be killed by the system when it needs to reclaim resources.

You can also read about controlling the lifecycle here: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#controlling-the-lifecycle-of-realm-instances